# Search text file for month, than output information linked to it

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

I need to search a text file, and using the month, then collect information from it.

The archive says information like:

```
01-Jan-2012 ED521D  4   100 30  1499    M   N Brewer
```

I need to pick out the "jan" and then use the other information. 
My code looks like:

```
            String chosenMonth = chooseMonth(); //asks user for month, which is then shortened to first 3 letters
            Scanner entries = readPolicy(); //this brings up the policy.txt

            int monthCount = 0;

            while (entries.hasNextLine()) {
                dates = entries.next();
                String clientDate = dates.substring(3, 6);

                if (clientDate.equalsIgnoreCase(chosenMonth)) {
                    monthCount++; // this is supposed to increment the monthCount everytime it finds the month
                }
                refNo = entries.next();
                itemNo += (entries.nextInt());
                clientValue = entries.nextInt();
                clientExcess = entries.nextInt();
                clientPremium += entries.nextInt();
                termString = entries.next();
                clientName = entries.nextLine();
            }

            String clientDate = dates.substring(3, 6);


            if (clientDate.equalsIgnoreCase(chosenMonth)) {
                int average = getChosenAverage(termString, monthCount, itemNo); //uses terms string to find entries that are marked m, the item no (which is collected and added to everytime it loops through) is then divided by the monthCount.
                int averagePremium = getChosenAveragePremium(termString, monthCount, clientPremium);//same here except premium is divided by monthCount
                displayPolicyMonth(chosenMonth, monthCount, average, averagePremium);
```

However its not working and gives me an exception.

The code for the getChosenAveragePremium is:

```
private static int getChosenAverage(String t, int m, int i) {
    int a = 0;
    char term = t.charAt(0);

    if (term == 'A' || term == 'M') {
        a = i / m;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: where is the exception, what is it?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero 
which is to do with the getChosenAveragePremium
as it finds a problem with clientpremium / monthCount

Comment: Can you post getChosenAveragePremium method?

Comment: put it in the question!

Comment: `monthCount` must be equal to `0` then.

Comment: Month count is 0.
Check the condition below, it must be returning false
`if (clientDate.equalsIgnoreCase(chosenMonth)) `
                }

Comment: but i know that it shouldnt be! the archive text has multiple records from every month, so it should increment everytimes it goes through it

Comment: But its not. Print `clientDate` and `chosenMonth` strings before `if` statement for debugging.

Comment: yeah, theyre returned as dec and 0 respectively. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, without any exceptions, using the same text line you provided. The problem in your code was  the equalsIgnoreCase() method. Replacing it by a contains() fixed the issue. (I have stripped it a bit to avoid having to add many variables)

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        clientDate = sc.next();
        String readMonth = clientDate.substring(3, 6);

        if (clientDate.contains(chosenMonth)) {
            System.out.println(readMonth);
            monthCount++;


            sc.next();
            itemNo += (sc.nextInt());
            sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextInt();
            clientPremium += sc.nextInt();
            termString = sc.next();
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        else
            sc.nextLine();
    }

    if (clientDate.contains(chosenMonth)) {
        int average = getChosenAverage(termString, monthCount, itemNo); 
        int averagePremium = getChosenAveragePremium(termString, monthCount, clientPremium);
        System.out.println(average + "\n" + averagePremium);
    }
```